# Print M x N grid with character inside each grid

Tags: python, string

I need to write a function called print_grid.

And the output when I call the print_grid function in main() should be:

[image]

Below are my code:

```
HORIZONTAL_WALL = "-"
VERTICAL_WALL = "|"
CORNER = "+"
EMPTY = " "
    
def print_grid(puzzle: str)-> None:
    i = 0
    while i < len(puzzle):
        print(CORNER + HORIZONTAL_WALL + HORIZONTAL_WALL + HORIZONTAL_WALL + CORNER)
        print(VERTICAL_WALL + EMPTY + puzzle[i] + EMPTY + VERTICAL_WALL)
        print(CORNER + HORIZONTAL_WALL + HORIZONTAL_WALL + HORIZONTAL_WALL + CORNER)
        i = i + 1
def main():
    print(print_grid("nevagonagiveu up"))
```

Let say if the puzzle = "nevagonagiveu up"

I have the output:

[image]

[image]

My code's output is different from the output I should have. I have tried a nested while loop, however it comes out to be an infinity loop. Can anyone solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the working loops to print the desired grid:

```py
from math import sqrt,ceil

def print_grid(s):
    grid_size = ceil(sqrt(len(s))) # A square size
    # print(grid_size)
    num_rows = 4 #grid_size
    num_cols = 5 #grid_size

    for row in range(num_rows):
        for col in range(num_cols-1):
            print("+---",end="")

        print("+---+")

        for col in range(num_cols):
            i = row*num_cols+col            
            c = s[i]  if i<len(s)  else " "

            print(f"+ {c} ",end="")

        print("+")

    for col in range(num_cols-1):
        print("+---",end="")

    print("+---+")

# Start
t="nevagonagiveu up"
print_grid(t)
```

[image]

Comment: Would you mind to explain grid_size = ceil(sqrt(len(s))) this line of code, I don't understand what is it for. Thank you

Comment: that grid_size is the width and height of the grid, u may use different numbers for rows and columns. The code is updated

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle the output line by line. For example:

```py
import math

   
def print_grid(s: str) -> None:
    n = math.ceil(math.sqrt(len(s)))
    for i in range(n):
        print('+---'*n+'+')
        print('|', end='')
        for j in range(n):
            char = s[i*n+j] if i*n+j < len(s) else " "
            print(' '+ char + ' ' + '|', end='')
        print()
        print('+---'*n+'+')

def main():
    print_grid("nevagonagiveu up")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


>>> python print_grid.py
+---+---+---+---+
| n | e | v | a |
+---+---+---+---+
+---+---+---+---+
| g | o | n | a |
+---+---+---+---+
+---+---+---+---+
| g | i | v | e |
+---+---+---+---+
+---+---+---+---+
| u |   | u | p |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the main issue that you had with this is that you looked at the boxes individually rather than as parts of a whole. You definitely want to do nested loops here, keeping track of 2 variables and subscripting puzzle using them. Here is what the code looks like when you do that. Another thing is that you can set the `end` parameter in print() to make it not go to a newline each time.

```
HORIZONTAL_WALL = "-"
VERTICAL_WALL = "|"
CORNER = "+"
EMPTY = " "

m = 4
n = 4

def print_grid(puzzle: str)-> None:
    def printHorizontalLine():
        print(CORNER, end='')
        for j in range(n):
            print(HORIZONTAL_WALL + HORIZONTAL_WALL + HORIZONTAL_WALL + CORNER, end='')
        print('')
    
    printHorizontalLine()
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            if (j == 0):
                print(VERTICAL_WALL, end='')
            print(EMPTY + puzzle[i*m+j] + EMPTY + VERTICAL_WALL, end='')
        print('')
        printHorizontalLine()

def main():
    print_grid("nevagonagiveu up")

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make some tweak in your code and check out this:

```
HORIZONTAL_WALL = "-"
VERTICAL_WALL = "|"
CORNER = "+"
EMPTY = " "
    
def print_grid(puzzle: str)-> None:
    puzzle_sub = [puzzle[i:i+4] for i in range(len(puzzle)) if (i)%4 == 0] 
    len_x = 4
    len_y = 4
   
    def call():
        for j in range(len_x+1):
            if j == len_x:
                print(CORNER)
                break
            print(CORNER,end="")
            print(HORIZONTAL_WALL + HORIZONTAL_WALL + HORIZONTAL_WALL,end="")

    for i in range(len_y+1):
        if i == len_y:
            call()
            break

        call()
        for j in range(len_x+1):
            if j == len_x:
                print(VERTICAL_WALL)
                break
            print(VERTICAL_WALL,end="")
            print(EMPTY + puzzle_sub[i][j] + EMPTY, end="")

   
def main():
    print_grid("nevagonagiveu up")

main()
```